# <form> action not being relative

Tags: html, forms, submit, action

This is a pretty basic question :D

I have an HTML at localhost/book which has a form,

```
    <form action="d" method="get">
      <input name="q" placeholder="Book name"></br>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

- The d action meant to be relative to current URL, which localhost/book, right?
  , so clicking Search should go like `localhost/book/d?q=some+data`
- But instead, it goes like `localhost/d?q=some+data`.
- How do I make it goes to `localhost/book/d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a URL-Issue: Because your current URL is lacking a trailing slash (/) the last part of the URL is not treated as a folder but a "file" instead. So if you submit the form it will go on level up in your case.

One solution would be to add a trailing slash in the URL. This could be done by rewrite on web-server level. Or you could change the link, but in that case you are never safe if the visitor is typing a slash or not.

The safer solution would be not to use a relative URL in the action of the form.

Comment: Thank you very much :) That was the case. I put a slash at the end.

Comment: Glad to hear! But always keep in mind: If this would be in the open field and if a user has/is able to enter the URL then you never know if there is a trailing slash or not. So your server should check for this and do a proper redirection. 

Good article on this (from Google):
[Slash or not to Slash](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash)

Answer (score 0):

For being relative to parent directory, please use

`action = "../d"`